# python_file_split and assigne_to_variables

Tags: python

i want to split a file (info.txt) which consist of lines of text for EG

```
1 ron texas
2 tim california
3 bob oregan 
4 john florida
5 marry virginia
```

after spliting this file i want them to assign into variables such as:-

`id`
`name`
`location`

Comment: Write some code to open up the file -> read one line at a time into a string -> then split that string by delimiter of space -> which will return a list of values of your three columns

Comment: @ScottStensland: Using the default delimiter is more versatile than using space, since it removes _all_ whitespace on the line, including the newline at the end of the line.

Comment: Yes true,  I mentioned the process of splitting on a delimiter of space char to invoke some context of what needs to happen

Answer (score 1):

Open the file, iterate over the lines, split the line (defaults on whitespace), and print it:

```
with open("info.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        ID, name, location = line.split()
        print("ID: {}, Name: {}, Location: {}".format(ID, name, location))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read file line by line and create tuple for each line. Something like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        entry = line.split()
        entry = (entry[0], entry[1], entry[2]) # (id, name, location
        # do what you want with entry
```